# Rails 3 Pagination for NON-ActiveRecord results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, ruby-on-rails-3

My rails 3 app uses [sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/) to perform search on text files, and I return a collection of results on the landing page view: something like

```
<%= render :partial => "result", :collection => @results %>
```

What is the Rails way to do pagination for the results? I know there are plugins like will_paginate, but I'm not using ActiveRecord (my app doesn't even use a db).

Is a Javascript solution the best way to go? I want to also maintain REST in the url, ie "/search?query=hello&page=2"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is someone who has already done so: [How to use will_paginate with non-ActiveRecord collection/array](http://www.pathf.com/blogs/2008/06/how-to-use-will_paginate-with-non-activerecord-collectionarray/)